# How can my code accommodate modding/plugins?

Tags: java, api, plugins

In general, how can I write programs to accommodate modding or plugins? Is every method wrapped with other behaviors? All my searching has led to are resources for writing plugins and mods themselves; I can't find anything on writing the systems. With regards to java, how do I expose internal portions of the logic to other systems without using reflection?

Comment: Look into [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). In a simple model, "extensions" will implement one or more interfaces which will in turn consume one or more "host" interfaces. That is, the internal logic is not exposed directly, but only through defined contracts. By using interfaces the code is generally free to pass around either the *actual* objects (hidden behind interfaces) or proxy/facade objects (that also implement said interfaces) - between the host and extension, however, there are only the interfaces/contracts.

Comment: So I should write my own implementations/behavior as one of many possible behaviors, and allow plugins to specify their own implementations and extend my classes? What if there is behavior regarding one component I want to guarantee, but also allow plugins to extend?

Comment: It's all about determining exactly *what* should be extended, and *how*. Is it adding a rule to the end of a series of rules? Is it adding a new dispatch/handler for a certain condition? Is it supplying default values? Is it supplying a replacement component? Is it reacting to/overriding events?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by creating your own ClassLoader that can load classes from a specified location that is not on the system classpath.  (If it is on the system classpath, the system ClassLoader will find the classes first and you won't be able to unload them.)  Creating instances requires a bit of reflection, but once they're created you can treat them just like any other instances.

This works because although only the custom ClassLoader knows about the actual class of those instances, it gets its definition of their superclass (your plugin class or interface) from the system ClassLoader.  Therefore, other classes loaded by the system ClassLoader (i.e., the rest of your program) can reference those dynamically created instances by their superclass.

I've used [Brian's Clapper's utility library](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/) to find classes that extend my plugin class.